# Visual Studio Installer Project .NET Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10, registry, installation

currently I am working on an installer setup for a c# application. To do this I am using the [Visual Studio Installer Project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects).

After creating the installer, I test it on another Windows 10 computer and it saying that it needs the .NET framework. I tried deleting it in the installer configuration within visual studio but its saying that this element cannot be removed from the installer. The problem is that the .NET Framework 3.5 installation on any computer around me cannot be proceed successfully (the progress bar stops in the middle and the installer stops). Is there a way to include the framework already during the c# setup installation?

Second question is regarding to registry keys. When I want to make a registry keyfor my .exe application do I only have to create an InstallDir Path Variable in the registry view within the installer configuration? And which path should there be written?

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge, the installer projects have been deprecated a few Visual Studio Version ago. Between [MSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer), InstallShield/other installer Programms, AppShops, ClickOnce and all the other channels - there was not really a need for a project anymore. It would also have worked poorly now that .NET Platform independance has finally come, as the pathing tends to be very different. Nevermind the concept of a Registery. So I am not sure how many people can help you with this.

If you want to keep at it, you could try lowering the Target Framework to something under 3.5. Also .NET Core is a seperate Framework installtion, just like Mono would be. Maybe you could point it to that one instead?

> The problem is that the .NET Framework 3.5 installation on any computer around me cannot be proceed successfully (the progress bar stops in the middle and the installer stops). Is there a way to include the framework already during the c# setup installation?

The Installer would just call the .NET Framework installer like you or Windows Update does right now. So it would likely just hang at a new place.

While slightly off topic, I think you need to deal with the root cause:

I never even heard of a .NET Update being broken like that. It should not be a general incompatibility either, as 3.5 is officially supported anywhere from XP to Windows 10 and even Server 2016.

The failure to install .NET 3.5 does indicate a massive issue with the Windows Update process on those compuers that must be fixed. It should have take care of that literal years ago. If it failed at this, it failed in another spot too. When in doubt a reinstallation usually helps.

Something I did find usefull when dealing with Update problems (short of reinstalling) was clearing the Storage Folder used by Windows Update. It is \Windows\SoftwareDistribution. However it is in use while Windows Update is running. So you need to:

1. Pause the Windows Update Service
2. Rename and later delete our outright delete the folder.
3. Restart the Windows Update Service. It will re-created the folder if missing.

Some warnings:

- update stores all it's settings in there
- update also stores all the downloaded updates. So those have to be re-downlaoded
- Stuff like last searched and install time will also be lost. But as long as it works after, it is usually not an issue
- Update stores the list of "already installed Updates" in tha folder, removing it will force it a complete scan for installed updates just like on a fresh installation. So the first search after this will take forever